# Comic relief probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

> Let $X_0,X_1,...$ be i.i.d and let $N = \inf \{ n\ge 1:X_n >X_0 \}$.
>
> Prove that $P(N>n) \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$.

My attempt,for $E = \{N>n\} = \{N = n+1 ,n+2,n+3,...\}$ and we know for $\{N = n+k\}$ means for the first $n+k+1$ element the first one i.e. $X_0$ rank exactly $n+k$, and $X_{n+k}$ rank exactly $n+k+1$, which means it has probability $\frac{1}{(n+k+1)(n+k)}$ by symmetric reasoning.Hence the sum for all $N>n$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

What I don't understand is why it may greater than $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

This is the example from Durrett probability page 70.Comic relief

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the case where all the $X_i$'s are 0. What is $N$? That should hopefully be enlightening to tell you where the symmetry argument fails, and that it is indeed exact if $P(X_i = X_j) = 0$